# How to change colors in react-native-chart-kit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, charts

I have a react-native-chart-kit ProgressChart, and I want three different colors for each data I have, but no matter what I do, I only get I color, with three different opacity.

How can I create a chart with three colors?

```
const CHARTCONFIG_PROGRESS = {
  backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 0.5,
  backgroundGradientToOpacity: 1,
  backgroundColor: "#1cc910",
  backgroundGradientFrom: "#F0BB62",
  backgroundGradientTo: "#519259",
  decimalPlaces: 0,
  color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 110, 199, ${opacity})`, //Here I can only define one color, and only the opacity will change
}


export const AllActivityDuration= ({animalData, title}) => {
    const [pieChart,setPieChart] = useState(null)

    useEffect(()=>{
        CreateData(animalData)
    },[])

    async function CreateData(animal){
        let labels = ["Játék","Futás", "Séta" ]
        let x

        await queryTimeSpentOnActivity(animal).then((result)=>{
            x = [result.playing/100,result.running/100, result.walking/100]
        })

        setPieChart({
          labels: labels, 
          data:x,
          colors: [         //Colors defined here are not working
            "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
            "rgb(60, 179, 113)",
            "rgb(255, 172, 71)",
          ]
        })
    }


    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{title}</Text>

        {pieChart ? 
        <ProgressChart
        data={pieChart}
        width={WINDOW_WIDTH-16}
        height={220}
        strokeWidth={16}
        radius={32}
        chartConfig={CHARTCONFIG_PROGRESS}
        hideLegend={false}
        style={{borderRadius:5, marginTop:10}}
        />
        : null}
      </View>
    );
};
```

Here is a screenshot of the current chart:

[image]